# Angular 2 export class: Declaration or statement expected

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to wrap my head around Angular 2 directives. In my code sample, I'm trying to mimic ngIf functionality. So I have a app.mycustomdirective.ts file:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({ 
    selector: '[my-custom-if]'
})

export class MyCustomIfDirective {

constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

@Input() set my-custom-if(condition: boolean) {
    if (condition) {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

I added it to my declarators:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyErrorDirective } from './app.myerrordirective';
import {MyCustomIfDirective} from './app.mycustomifdirective';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, MyErrorDirective, MyCustomIfDirective ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally I add it to my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h2 *my-custom-if="condition">Hello {{name}}</h2>
            <button (click)="condition = !condition">Click</button>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { 
    name = 'Angular'; 
    condition = false;  
}
```

Now, when I try `npm start` I get the following error:

```
src/app/app.mycustomifdirective.ts(13,17): error TS1005: '(' expected.
src/app/app.mycustomifdirective.ts(13,25): error TS1109: Expression expected.
src/app/app.mycustomifdirective.ts(13,37): error TS1005: ')' expected.
src/app/app.mycustomifdirective.ts(13,46): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/app.mycustomifdirective.ts(20,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

And I can't figure out what's happening. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: you cannot have '-' in function name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error come from this:

```
@Input() set my-custom-if(condition: boolean) { // error
               ^  ^  ^
```

You can try this one:

```
@Input() myCustomIf: boolean;
init () {
   if (this.myCustomIf) {
       // your code here
   }
}
```

Then just call, `this.init()` into your `constructor`.

Follow this [guide](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) step by step.